Installing packages within running Postgresql Container in Kubernetes Cluster
There have been many related posts, but I am trying to install some packages (dnsutils, get), etc within the running Postgresql container hosted in the Kubernetes cluster. my Kubernetes cluster is RKE2 binaries.
I cannot use docker as my RKE2 cluster does not support docker so I tried to use runc but was still not able to log in as root into the container.
I want to use kubectl exec into the container and install some packages but it requires root privileges and I need to install sudo within the container which I am not able to install.
kubectl exec -it <pod name> -- bin/bash

$ apt-get update
var/lib/apt/lists/partial is missing
$ apt-get upgrade
could not open the lock file /var/lib/dpkg/locl-frontend - open (13: permission denied)

If I try to run with sudo inside the container i.e
:/$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo not found
I also tried to enter in root user mode within the container, it is asking the password which I do not know which password need to enter
:/$ su -
Password:
I have tried everything but nothing is working.
Any suggestion would be appreciated

This question is similar to: E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The given above link has not given proper answer, my issue is further than that which I have already mentioned .i.e if i run sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade, it says: sudo not found. I have made it more clear now

Possible duplicate of sudo: command not found

not really, when I try to run 'sudo' inside container which gives me the above error as mentioned in the description. As I said it looks similar but not exactly has been addresed further issue

I retracted my close vote, so your question is back to normal now.
